# Removing contents of two files at the same time - UNIX

Tags: file, design-patterns

I have two files called "fileA.txt" and "fileB.txt".

fileA.txt has the following contents :

```
1   Arizona   ABDJAQ   224
2   Ohio      AKOGFR   458
3   Wisconsin EFGTAP   871
4   Colorado  NAHBAX   991
```

The four columns above are "ID", "State", "Pattern", "Number"

fileB.txt has the following contents:

```
1   Arizona   NKIGAB   763
2   Ohio      BAVYAD   918
3   Wisconsin AUOBAQ   547
4   Colorado  INABEA   622
```

Again the four columns are "ID", "State", "Pattern", "Number"

Now this is what I want to do:

I want to scan through "fileA.txt" first and remove all records whose "Pattern" column just has one "A". Keep all records that have 2 "A"'s in them. So I would remove Ohio and Wisconsin. (ID "2" and ID "3"). At the same time, I want to simultaneously remove these ID's from "fileB.txt" as well !! (inspite of the fact that in fileB, Ohio and Wisconsin have 2 "A"'s in the pattern).

After this step, my "fileA.txt" should look like :

```
1   Arizona   ABDJAQ   224
4   Colorado  NAHBAX   991
```

and my "fileB.txt" should look like :

```
1   Arizona   NKIGAB   763
4   Colorado  INABEA   622
```

Next, I want to scan "fileB.txt" to remove any records with patterns having one "A" and delete the corresponding record from "fileA.txt". (in this case Arizona because it has only "A" in fileB and so we remove Arizona from both fileB and fileA.)

After this step, I would be left with only one record in each file :

"fileA.txt" will have:

```
4   Colorado  NAHBAX   991
```

and "fileB.txt" will have

```
4   Colorado  INABEA   622
```

So, to put it in short, I want to scan both files and keep only those records which have 2 "A"'s in their pattern in BOTH files.

Is there a one-line Unix command or a relatively easy approach to do this ?

appreciate the help !

Comment: I bet someone is gonna come up with an `awk` one-liner for this.

Comment: I hope so. I have written a Python script for this, however, I really really want a one-liner.

Comment: Python script is quite ok. Why do you want a oneliner? This does not seem a trivial operation - you used a whole screen to describe it :).

Answer (score 0):

I have written one-liner in a Python(*280 characters of code*) for this.

```
python -c"import re,sys;o=lambda f,m:open(f,m);x=lambda h:[i for i in o(h,'r').readlines()];y=lambda s:len(re.findall(r'(\w+)',s)[2].split('A'))>2;z=lambda f,s:o(f,'a'if len(s)else'w').write(s);a,b=sys.argv[1:3];w=zip(x(a),x(b));z(a,'');z(b,'');[(z(a,c),z(b,d))for(c,d)in w if y(c)and y(d)]" a.txt b.txt
```

Note: this code does not close file descriptors. I assume that OS does that.